# NetBeans not stopping on some breakpoints in PHP code

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, breakpoints, phalcon

I have problem with xdebug because don't stop in some breakpoints.

My project have MVC architecture and all worked fine with debugging while I created subcontrollers, because in subcontrollers breakpoints not working. If I put `xdebug_break()` in subcontroller then it works.

I checked xdebug_remote.log

This breakpoint not working

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 1309 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/my_project/app/controllers/settings/LanguageController.php -n 18
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="1309" state="enabled" id="59770002"></response>
```

This breakpoint working

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 1310 -t line -s enabled -f file:///var/www/my_project/app/controllers/IndexController.php -n 15
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="1310" state="enabled" id="59770003"></response>
```

It's possible, that namespace is guilty? One difference between controller and subcontroller is namespace. In controller is it not defined, but in subcontroller is defined.

Comment: Namespace? -- very unlikely (the code itself may not have worked in such case). What sort of lines they are -- show a screenshot of that non-working breakpoint please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I changed the namespace to lowercase before was in camelcase and I changed register namespace on exactly folder structure.

**Before in controller:**

```
namespace MyApp\Controllers\Settings;
```

in loader.php

```
$loader->registerNamespaces( [ 'MyApp\Controllers\Settings' => DIR.'/../controllers/settings' ] )->register();
```

**After (properly working)**

in controller:

```
namespace app\controllers\settings;
```

in loader.php

```
$loader->registerNamespaces( [ 'app\controllers\settings' => DIR.'/../controllers/settings' ] )->register();
```